# Documentation for Roles and permissions

Tags: marketing-cloud, permissions, roles

Does anyone know where I can find some documentation or a description of the roles and permissions found in the account 'Roles'?

I have looked into the documentation and have not been able to find any up to date information containing all the roles.

[image: User Roles]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the documentation that provides the roles specified above that also provides a description. For some reason they are listed in 2 seperate locations but this should cover the list specified in your screenshot.

**Predefined roles:**

[**Enterprise 2.0 Overview - Predefined Roles**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000231043&type=1)

**SMC roles:**

[**Marketing Cloud - SMC Roles**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/marketing_cloud/smc_roles/)